# How do I copy extra files to an Xcode archive?

Tags: xcode, build, archive

I have an Xcode project set up with a "Copy Files" Build Phase, and "Destination" set to "Products Directory" and a subpath of "help".

When I *build* my product this successfully copies my files to the "help" directory, which is a sibling of the main built product.

However when I *Archive* my product, the resulting Archive **does not** contain the additional files, only the main application.

Is it possible to have additional files copied to an Archive? If so, how?

I have the "Skip Install" build setting set to "Yes", but this doesn't seem to make any difference.